# Determinant of the sum of an orthogonal and a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am starting from the lemma
\begin{equation}
1+x^TGx = \frac{det(G^{-1} + xx^T)}{det(G)}
\end{equation}
where $det(G)=-1$ and $G$ is an orthogonal matrix. I am trying to find some bounds on the left hand side of the above equation, by bounding the determinant on the right hand side. Can anyone help me with this? The determinant $det(G^{-1} + xx^T)$ is the part causing me trouble. It may also be useful to note that these $G$ form a cyclic finite group of order $N$ (even), i.e. $G^N=\mathbb{I}$.

Answer (score 1):

For rank 1 updates to a matrix, there is the following general formula:
$$
\det(A + uv^T) = \det(A) \cdot (1 + v^T A^{-1} u)
$$
which becomes in your case
$$
\det(O + xx^T) = \det(O) \cdot (1 + x^T O^Tx).
$$
See the [Matrix determinant lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma).

Comment: thank you. I should have stated, I am working from the matrix determinant lemma, and trying to find $1+x^T0x$ in terms of $det(O_xx^T)$

Comment: @jdizzle - $\det O x x^T = 0$ since this is a rank 1 matrix. Or is there a misprint?

Comment: sorry, my original question was not very clear! I have rephrased it